# Custom Report Filter logic in VF page

Tags: apex, custom-reports

I have created VF page that get data from report and bind in VF page.
There is also filter functionality implemented for this custom reoport.

Now I have requirement to add Report Filter Logic like we use in standard report filter i.e. (1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4)).
But, I am not able to add it in Apex Class.

```
    Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(REPORT_ID);
Reports.ReportMetadata reportMetadata = describe.getReportMetadata();
List<Reports.ReportFilter> lstFilters = new List<Reports.ReportFilter>();

if(String.isNotBlank(strSpread)) {
    String[] spaceSize = strSpread.split(' ');
    if(spaceSize[0].contains('-')) {
        lstFilters.addAll(addRangeFilter('Deal_Quotes__c.Spread__c',spaceSize[0].split('-')[0].trim(), spaceSize[0].split('-')[1].trim()));
    } else if(getEndRangeString(spaceSize[spaceSize.size()-1]) != '') {
        String strrange = getEndRangeString(spaceSize[spaceSize.size()-1]);
        lstFilters.addAll(addRangeFilter('Deal_Quotes__c.Spread__c',
                                        strrange == 'above' ? spaceSize[0].trim() : null,
                                        strrange == 'above' ? null : spaceSize[0].trim()));
    }
}
if(String.isNotBlank(dateRangeFrom)) {
    lstFilters.add(new Reports.ReportFilter('Deal_Quotes__c.Quote_Date__c', 'greaterOrEqual', dateRangeFrom));
}
if(String.isNotBlank(dateRangeTo)) {
    lstFilters.add(new Reports.ReportFilter('Deal_Quotes__c.Quote_Date__c', 'lessOrEqual', dateRangeTo));
}

if(lstFilters.size() > 0) {
    reportMetadata.setReportFilters(lstFilters);
}
return Reports.ReportManager.runReport(REPORT_ID, reportMetadata, true);
```

Above is my code. Please give me suggestion, where should I add the filter logic?

Comment: What issue you are facing in above code?

Comment: This not an answer but look at composite design pattern that shoulp you build complex logics https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Composite

Comment: What do you mean "I am not able to add it in Apex Class"?  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much [codeyinthecloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/55478/codeyinthecloud),

This help me a lot https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Composite

Comment: Can you let me know how you build the custom filter logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAVASCRIPT function in your VF page to filter logic i.e. (1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4)). It's Report Builder JS function of Saleforce.

You can find it in "../analytics-reporting-impl/ReportFilterPanel.js".

Ref: [Implement Salesforce filter Criteria Logic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237373/implement-salesforce-filter-criteria-logic/237391#237391)